# Weird error when overloading functions in TS

Tags: typescript

Say we have the following overload signatures and implementation:

```js
function f(n: number): number;
function f(n: string): string;
function f(n: number | string) {
  return n;
}
```

Even though TS infers the function argument `n` to be of type `number | string` inside of the function body, the snippet type checks without any problems because TS understands that the return type will match the actual type of `n`. So far so good.

Let's change the implementation to:

```js
function f(n: number | string) {
    if (typeof n === "number") {
        return n;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Still type checks. In the body of the `if` statement the type of `n` is inferred to be `number` and outside of it to be `string`, so the contract holds.

But if we return some static `string` or `number` in one of the branches, then we suddenly get an error:

```js
function f(n: number): number; // This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)
function f(n: string): string; 
function f(n: number | string) {
    if (typeof n === "number") {
        return 42;
    }
    return n;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You just need to specify the return type of the function implementing the overloads `: number | string`

Comment: That works, thanks. Although it still confuses me that the behavior changes once you return something static. I would have expected either an error in both cases or no error at all.

Comment: `n` is `number` in the first case, so it fits the return type of `number`. However, in the second case the return type is not widened, and it's `string | 42` which does not match `string | number`. I guess slightly unexpected but not unusual if you have implicit typing. Some times they just aren't accurate, so using explicit types solves the issues.

Comment: You could also do -> `n = 42; return n;`  or `return 42 as typeof n;` , or `return 42 as number;`  etc.  to keep some form of implicit typing.   I like to keep type's close to the return, rather than the call signature, but that's maybe just me..

Comment: Since `42` is static, you can make it as a return type. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/mx8jGm)

Comment: I think this aspect of TS got me for a while `42` in TS is actually a type, so `42` != `number`,.   Another alternative, might just be `return Number(42)`, this and the others, basically widen the type to `number`, and not `42`..

Comment: Thanks a bunch guys, so the missing type widening was the problem here. Totally forgot about that!